# datepicker in android need to check weekend

Tags: java, android

I am doing datepicker. I am facing some challenges. I am checking wheather selected date is weekend or not. If it is weekend then it should give current date only. Now I don't know where should I put condition in this program and how to get the day of the week and against which thing I should check.
    Please, help me.

```
     // TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener
{
    //Declaration for class
    ButtonViews views;
    dpListener dpListenerView;
    // Declartion for member vairables
    int day, month, x_year;
    int hour;
    int minute;
    Calendar calendar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        views = new ButtonViews();
        dpListenerView = new dpListener();

        //ButtonListener
        views.button_date.setOnClickListener(this);
        views.button_time.setOnClickListener(this);
        //

       // pick up the default date using Calender class
         calendar =  GregorianCalendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"), Locale.getDefault());

        curr_date();

        hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        setupDate(day, month, x_year);
        setupTime(hour, minute);
   }

    public void curr_date(){
        day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        x_year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button_date:
                showDatePickerDialog();
                break;
            case R.id.button_time:
   /*               showTimePickerDialog();*/
                break;
        }
    }


    private void setupTime(int hours, int minutes) {
        views.button_time.setText(hours + ":" + minutes);
    }

    private void setupDate(int day, int month, int year) {

        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");

        String strMonth = ((month + 1) <= 9) ? ("0" + (month + 1)) : String.valueOf(month + 1);
        views.button_date.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/" + strMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
        String strDate = String.valueOf(day) + "/" + strMonth + "/" + String.valueOf(year);
        Date d = null;
        try {
            d = (Date) sdf.parse(strDate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        calendar.setTime(d);
        int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
        if(dayOfWeek == 7 || dayOfWeek == 1) {
            Toast.makeText(DateTimePickerActivity.this,"You have chosen weekend",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        }

    }
    private void showDatePickerDialog() {
        DatePickerDialog datepickerdialog = new DatePickerDialog
                (
                        this,
                         dpListenerView,
                       /* new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                            } },*/
                        //this,
                        x_year,
                        month,
                        day
                );
        datepickerdialog.show();
    }

   class ButtonViews {
        Button button_time;
        Button button_date;

        public ButtonViews() {
            button_date = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_date);
            button_time = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_time);
        }
    }

  class dpListener implements OnDateSetListener {
      @Override
      public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        setupDate(dayOfMonth, monthOfYear, year);



       /*  if(dayOfWeek == 7 || dayOfWeek == 1) {*/
              // as your requirement: you should display message they can not select the weekend" here
              // then you set the value in datepickerdialog by current date
//              Toast.makeText(DateTimePickerActivity.this
//                      , "You have selected weekend  ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         // }

      }

   }
}
```